# Сайт на другом компьютере выглядит не так, как надо

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Верстал сайт на широкоформатном компьютере, все было хорошо при изменении размера окна браузера.
Затем решил зайти с недавно появившегося ноутбука с размером экрана 1366x768 и обнаружил проблему, которую можно видеть на скриншоте: размер кнопок меню, шрифт, логотип и прочее.
Подозреваю, что связано как-то с тем, что величины у меня в указаны vh, а на данном ноутбуке высота меньше, чем на пргошлом экране, с которого верстал.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
@import url("/css/oblacheniya.css");
@import url("/css/oblacheniya-type-select.css");
@import url("/css/product-page.css");
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz');

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #B63D32;
}
#page-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#content-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 2vh solid black;
  border-left: 2vh solid black;
  border-right: 2vh solid black;
  border-bottom: 1vh solid black;
}
.container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.logo {
    width: 11.1vh;
    height: 11vh;
    padding-top: 0.8vh;
    padding-right: 11.5vh;
  }
.logo img {
    width: 11.3vh;
    height: 11vh;
    margin: 0vh auto;
    padding-top: 0vh;
}
.main_title {
    padding-top: 0.2vh;
    margin-left: 0vh;
    padding-right: 0vh;
    font-size: 4vh;
    font-family: ImpactI, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0vh 0.4vh rgba(0, 0, 0, .34);
    text-align: center;
}
.subtitle {
  font-size: 2vh;
  font-family: Lobster, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.14vh;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -0.3vh;
  padding-right: 0vh
}
.second_subtitle {
    font-size: 2.3vh;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: ImpactI, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 0.1vh 0.05vh 0.3vh rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    background-color: #666666;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    letter-spacing: -0.055vh;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -0.2vh;
}
.top_navigation-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1.5vh;
    text-align: center;
}
.top_navigation-menu li {
  width: 100%;
}
.top_navigation-menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.top_navigation-menu li{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.top_navigation-menu li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2.35vh;
    font-family: Courier New Cyr, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
.container1 ul {
  padding-bottom: 0vh;
  margin-bottom: 0vh;
}
.container1 ul li {
  padding-bottom: 0vh;
  margin-bottom: 0vh;
}
.container1 ul li>a:hover {
  color: black;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 114vh;
}
/*ЛЕВОЕ МЕНЮ*/
/*ЛЕВОЕ МЕНЮ*/
.spisok {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #7B2019;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*border*/
  border-top: 1.6vh solid black;
  border-bottom: 2vh solid #000;
  border-left: 1.5vh solid #000;
  border-right: 0vh solid #000;
  /*border ends*/
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.spisok li {
  width: 24vh;
  list-style-image: none;
  height: 5.5vh;
  background-image: url(/img/span_menu.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: center no-repeat;
  transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  margin-top: 0.45vh;
}

#oblacheniya {
  
}
.spisok li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: CyrillicOldBold, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.05vh;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2vh;
  font-weight: normal;
  }

.spisok ul>li:hover {
  background-image: url(/img/span_menu_hover.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: center no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.spisok ul li>a:hover {
  text-shadow: gold 0 0 4vh;
  /* Свечение голубого цвета */
  color: white;
}
ul {
  padding-left: 0vh;
}
.button.block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 0vh;
}
.spisok ul {
  list-style-image: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -o-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;

}
.spisok ul li a p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#ugol {
  background-image: url(/img/span_menu_black.png);
}

.text-div {
  width: 15.8vh;
  height: 3vh;
}

.letter-spacing {
  letter-spacing: 0.1vh;
}

.ryasi {
  letter-spacing: 0.2vh;
}
/*Начало SECTION*/
section {
  background: url(/img/fon.png);
  background-color: #BFBFBF;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  height: 114vh;
  /*РАМКА*/
  border-left: 2vh solid black;
  border-top: 0vh solid black;
  border-right: 2vh solid black;
  border-bottom: 0vh solid black;
  /*Конец РАМКИ*/
}

.container2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 109.9vh;
}

.Nashi_Tseny {
  width: 100%;
  height: 106.9vh;
}
.photo-price {
  height: 100vh;
}

.text-price {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 98vh;
  border: solid transparent;
  border-width: 25vh 10vh 15vh 10vh;
  border-image: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/wky2z.png);
  border-image-slice: 800 250 338;
  border-image-repeat: round;
}
.text-price {
  font-size: 2.3vh;
  font-family: Yanone Kaffeesatz, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration-skip-ink:none;
}

.text-price p {
  padding-left: 2vh;
}
#first_abzac {
  margin-top: -2vh; 
}
.photo-price {
  height: 97vh;
  width: 100%;
}
.border-price {
  max-width: 10vh;
}
.choose_otstup {
 margin-left: 1vh;
}
h2 {
  margin-top: 3vh;
  font-size: 4.7vh;
  font-family: ImpactI;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-top: 0.5vh;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-skip-ink:none;
  text-align: center;
  
}

strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 2.1vh;
}

.vosem_tis {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Lobster, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.9vh;
}
/*НАЧАЛО FOOTER*/
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15vh;
  border-left: 2vh solid black;
  border-right: 2vh solid black;;
  border-top: 1vh solid black;;
  border-bottom: 2vh solid black;;
}
/*КОНЕЦ FOOTER*/
@media (max-width: 970px) {
.spisok li {

  width: 22vh;
  list-style-image: none;
  height: 5.5vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  background-image: url(/img/span_menu.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: center no-repeat;
  transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.spisok ul li a p {
  padding-top: 2vh;
  margin-top: 0.42vh;
}
}
@media (max-width: 920px) {
.spisok li {
  width: 16.5vh;
  list-style-image: none;
  height: 5.5vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  background-image: url(/img/span_menu.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: center no-repeat;
  transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
}
@media (max-width: 650px) {
#content-wrapper {
 width: 100%;
}
.spisok {
 display: none;
}
}
@media (max-width: 1325px) {
.spisok li {

  width: 20vh;
  list-style-image: none;
  height: 5.4vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  background-image: url(/img/span_menu.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: center no-repeat;
  transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
}
@media (max-width: 1250px) {
.spisok li {
  width: 20vh;
  list-style-image: none;
  height: 6.5vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  background-image: url(/img/span_menu.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: center no-repeat;
  transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
}
@media (max-width: 1295px) {
  .text-price {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90vh;
    height: 98vh;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 25vh 10vh 15vh 10vh;
    border-image: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/wky2z.png);
    border-image-slice: 800 250 338;
    border-image-repeat: round;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1155px) {
  .text-price {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70vh;
    height: 98vh;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 25vh 10vh 15vh 10vh;
    border-image: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/wky2z.png);
    border-image-slice: 800 250 338;
    border-image-repeat: round;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1090px) {
  .text-price {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70vh;
    height: 98vh;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 25vh 10vh 15vh 10vh;
    border-image: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/wky2z.png);
    border-image-slice: 800 250 338;
    border-image-repeat: round;
  }
  .spisok li {
    width: 16.5vh;
    list-style-image: none;
    height: 5.5vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    background-image: url(/img/span_menu.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: center no-repeat;
    transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
.spisok li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: CyrillicOldBold, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.05vh;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.6vh;
  font-weight: normal;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .text-price {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 60vh;
    height: 99vh;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 25vh 10vh 15vh 10vh;
    border-image: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/wky2z.png);
    border-image-slice: 800 250 338;
    border-image-repeat: round;
  }
  .spisok li {
    width: 15.8vh;
    list-style-image: none;
    height: 5.5vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    background-image: url(/img/span_menu.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: center no-repeat;
    transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
.spisok li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: CyrillicOldBold, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.05vh;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.4vh;
  font-weight: normal;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 360px) {
  header {
    border-top: 0.8vh solid black;
    border-left: 0.8vh solid black;
    border-right: 0.8vh solid black;
    border-bottom: 0.7vh solid black;
  }
  section {
    border-left: 0.8vh solid black;
    border-top: 0vh solid black;
    border-right: 0.8vh solid black;
    border-bottom: 0vh solid black;
  }
  .text-price {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 2.8vh;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 3vh;
  }
  .spisok li {
    width: 15.8vh;
    list-style-image: none;
    height: 5.5vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    background-image: url(/img/span_menu.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: center no-repeat;
    transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  .spisok li a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: CyrillicOldBold, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.05vh;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.4vh;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  .choose_otstup {
  margin-left: 1vh;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
  }
  strong {
  font-weight: italic;
}
.text-price p {
  margin-top: 2vh;
  margin-bottom: 0vh; 
  padding-left: 2vh;
}
}
```

```html
<?php  
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/objects/head.php';
?>
<?php  
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/header.php';
?>

  <main>
    
    <section>
     <div class="container2">
      <div class="Nashi_Tseny">
       <h2>Наши цены:</h2>
          <div class="photo-price">
           <div class="text-price">
              <p id="first_abzac"><u><b>Облачения</b></u>:</p>
                  <p class="choose_otstup">-иерейские <strong>шелковые</strong> от <strong><span class="vosem_tis">9000</span></strong> &nbsp; рублей с шикарными галунами</p>
                  <p class="choose_otstup">-иерейские <strong>парчевые</strong> от <strong><span class="vosem_tis">10000</span>&nbsp;</strong> рублей<strong>*</strong></p>
                 <p><u><b>Подрясники</b></u>:</p>
                 <p><u><b>Подризники</b></u>:</p>
                 <p><u><b>Рясы</b></u>:</p>
                 <p><u><b>Стихари</b></u>:</p>
                 <p><u><b>Скуфии</b></u>:&nbsp;от 800 рублей;</p>
                 <p><u><b>Камилавки</b></u>:&nbsp;от 1700</p>
                 <p><u><b>Крещальные</b></u>:</p>
                 <p><u><b>Облачения для храма</b></u>:</p>
                 <p><u><b>Вышитые кресты</b></u>:</p>
                 <p><u><b>Кадильный уголь</b></u>:</p>
                             <p class="choose_otstup">*парчевые облачения с индийскими галунами шьются по заказу</p>
                          </div>
         </div>
    </div>
    </section>
   </main>
<?php  
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/objects/footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: Ну, кроме как предложить вам не использовать vh здесь больше ответить нечего

Comment: @andreymal как тогда получить адаптивность по-другому? Мне посоветовали на этом сайте с помощь vh.

Comment: А просто не надо было доводить до абсурда, vh для шрифтов и всего связанного с ними применять не надо, для остального применяйте на здоровье :) Ну и естественно нужно было изначально проверять вёрстку на всех разрешениях — совсем необязательно тащиться к ноутбуку, никто не мешает вам просто уменьшать размер окна браузера на вашем широкоформатном компьютере

Comment: @andreymal я пользовался масштабированием окна, но только по ширине, на высоту не обращал внимания) Подскажите, в чем указывать размер шрифтов, чтобы они адаптировались под разрешения? Проценты?

Comment: Что конкретно вы имеете в виду под «адаптировались под разрешения»? В вашем случае они вполне адаптировались — уменьшились относительно высоты окна, как вы и прописали в vh :)

Comment: @andreymal ох, да, неверно выразился) Я хотел спросить, каким образом указывать значения, чтобы, например, текст был читаемым при любом соотношении размеров окна. Т.е. фиксированного размера по пропорциям.

Comment: Используйте любую фиксированную единицу измерения, например px

Comment: Кто-нибудь ещё, кроме автора, видит на скриншоте какую-нибудь проблему?